# Pass original component's function to react HOC

Tags: reactjs

I have created react HOC component as below.

```
const UpdatedComponent = (OriginalComponent) => {
    class NewComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        
            this.state = {
                 counter:0
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            
        }
    
        incrementCount = () => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {counter:prevState.counter+1}
            })
        }
        render(){

            return <OriginalComponent 
                incrementCount={this.incrementCount}
                count={this.state.counter}
            />
        }
    }

    return NewComponent
}

export default UpdatedComponent
```

and I am using that component in the below example

```
class HoverCounter extends Component {

   componentDidMount(){
      
   }

   handleMessages = () => {
       // need to do somthing
   }
    
    render() {
        const {incrementCount, count} = this.props
        return (
            <div onMouseOver={incrementCount}>
                Hoverd {count} times
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UpdatedComponent(HoverCounter)
```

I want to know that is it possible to pass

```
handleMessages()
```

function to HOC?

like this

```
    export default UpdatedComponent(HoverCounter,handleMessages)
```

I have no idea how to pass the original component function or props to HOC.

Answer (score 0):

you could get everyThing in your Hoc like this :

```
 const UpdatedComponent = (OriginalComponent , func) => {
  componentDidMount(){
      func()
  }
```

in HoverCounter also you could add this changes:

```
 static handleMessages(){
  // need to do something
  }

 export default UpdatedComponent(HoverCounter , HoverCounter.handleMessages)
```

Comment: Thank for reply. Yes I know some values can be pass. but want to know how to pass class function from original component for example handleMessage is class function of HoverCounter class. is that possible

Comment: yes you can. you can write like this:

   static handleMessages(){
      // need to do somthing
  }
  
  
export default UpdatedComponent(HoverCounter , HoverCounter.handleMessages)